# IDEA complains about Revolver.settings when trying to parse spray-template's build.sbt file

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, spray

I've cloned the Spray template project (branch `on_spray-can_1.1`) as suggested on Spray's "[Getting Started](http://spray.io/introduction/getting-started/)" page, and used [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) to generate a corresponding IDEA project. It builds fine, but when I open my `build.sbt` file, the last line makes IDEA unhappy:

```
seq(Revolver.settings: _*)
```

It doesn't recognize `Revolver`, and suggests importing `spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.Revolver`, which seems reasonable. However, when I do that, it still complains "Expression type (Def.SettingsDefinition) must conform to Setting[_] in SBT file".

Clearly this is not a real problem, or IDEA's (external) make would fail, and/or SBT would complain from the command line. But why does IDEA think it's a problem? Has something changed in recent versions of SBT?

When I look at the SBT 0.13.0 source I notice `seq` is deprecated; it says "In build.sbt files, this call can be removed." If I do that, however, Revolver stops working ("Not a valid command: re-start").

FWIW, I'm using SBT 0.13.0 with Scala 2.10.3 and IDEA 12.1.6 on Mint 14.

Comment: Try `gen-idea sbt-classifier` when generating the idea project from sbt.

Comment: That creates an IDEA module with all sources downloaded and attached, but doesn't seem to do anything about my actual problem AFAICT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to replace it by just

```
Revolver.settings
```

Comment: That works, but IDEA still says `"Expression type (Def.SettingsDefinition) must conform to Setting[_] in SBT file"`.

Comment: @DavidMoles, you can surpress the warning by using `Revolver.settings: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]`. Inside, it will be expanded to `Revolver.settings.settings`, which is funny to write:)

Comment: Thanks, it really removed the error IntelliJ showed, but still for some reason when I change class code and refresh on browser it doesn't update. In addition I added "spray-json" support, but I am unable to import it to the project. Any reason for that?

Comment: Regarding the first error: Do you use `~ re-start`?